# Creating an auto populating javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to populate two arrays in javascript to simulate timely updating chart.
For this I want two charts to be populate.

var array1 = [1,2,3,...]   //time in seconds
var array2 = [10,15,12,...]  //any random number

Each element should be pushed to the arrays with one second of interval.

Tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4ccr0hzg/5/) but arrays are not getting updated as I want.

```
var time = [];
var value = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
});

    function update() {
      var index = 0;
      setTimeout(function () {
        index++;
        time.push(index);
        value.push(Math.random() * (0 - 200));
        console.log(time)
        console.log(value)
        update();
      }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: Silly mistake of putting index inside the function. Updated it correctly.

Comment: don't fix your question now specially if it was the source of the main mistake. Otherwise the Answers will look silly.

Answer (score 3):

***[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/4ccr0hzg/7/)***

`var index = 0` It's not getting updated cause at every iteration you're resetting it to `0`. Move it outside of your `update()` fn

So try like:

```
var index = 0 ; // Outside the update fn scope
var time = [];
var value = [];

$(document).ready( update );

function update() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        time.push(++index);
        value.push( ~~(Math.random() * 200 ) + 1);
        console.log(time)
        console.log(value)
        update();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I was suspecting I wasn't reading the same thing ... let's clear up comments

Answer (score 1):

You should move `var index = 0;` outside of update function.

```js
var time = [];
var value = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
  update();
});
var index = 0;

function update() {

  setTimeout(function() {
    index++;
    time.push(index);
    value.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 200));
    console.log(time)
    console.log(value)
    update();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're after `setInterval` (*almost* same usage as `setTimeout` you're using).

Difference is, `setTimeout` runs the function once after the specified timeout, while `setInterval` runs repeatedly.

Also check out `clearInterval` (to be run on the return value of `setInterval`) which stops the execution of the function.

```
// to start
var interval = setInterval(function () { /* ... */ }, 1000);

// to stop
clearInterval(interval);
```

You also no longer need to invoke `update()` inside itself after switching functions.